# Scaling TextView animation without scaling text in it

Tags: android, animation, textview, scale

I have an animation:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 0.2f , 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    anim .setDuration(700);

    anim .setFillAfter(true);

    anim .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

and I start it for a TextView

```
    textView.startAnimation(anim);
```

It is scaling my textView from 0% to 20% of its width but it is also scaling text which is in my textView.

Is there any chance to scale TextView without scaling text size in it?

Comment: you can use ObjectAnimator to change margin of TextView programatically.